# Is it frowned upon to encourage a user to click the checkmark?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

I was sure I had seen this question on here before, but I searched and couldn't find it.

Occasionally, a new user will ask a question, and when I answer it, they comment on it saying that it helped them or solved the problem. Each time this happens, I'm tempted to comment on my answer something similar to this:

> @OP, if my answer solved the problem for you, you can accept my answer.

And then a link to a relevant help-page, such as https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer.

Is this frowned upon? I could understand if this was viewed as rep-whoring, but it also helps everyone if the question is marked as answered and the answer that helped the OP the most was pinned to the top.